# Socket object life cycle

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, lifecycle

I'm using `Socket` object for sending commands to other program over tcp.

I wonder what is a better decision:

1. To initialize `Socket` object on every command send/ receive session
   and then close it.
2. Or to initialize one global `Socket` object, use it to send all
   commands/receive responses and close on program close.

So the question is how often should i close the socket object for "same" operations?

Comment: It depends, but the first is the correct approach much less frequently. There's too little information here though.

Comment: @Jon , sorry, added more precise question. Just want to know what is better, to close socket after receiving response, or leave the object, reuse it to get more responses and do more send operations.

Comment: Are you trying a synchronous or asynchronous approach? Anyway I would take the your first suggestion, it seems to be a cleaner way in terms of resource handling.

Comment: @peer , asynchronous. So, i'll shutdown socket after i get response. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on you application requirements. e.g. 
let say you are writing an smtp client then the server would not allow you to connect for ever and this also is request/response type protocol (e.g. you send request to check any mail and receive response of it) then you must close your socket once your request is completed. 
but if you are writing some chat like application then you might dont want to close your socket. Because chat app server can send you other's chatter message any time as received at server so in this case server will also push you data without your request.